# Saving data to an array of pointers when reading form an file

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I do not understand why my array of pointers is only saving the last line from the file that I am reading from. When I substitute a string literal into the setData() function the code works just fine. All that the "mann" file contains are a bunch of words order alphabetically. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class orignialData {

char* data;

public:

    void setData(char* s) { data = s;}
    char* getData() const {return data;}
};

class dataClass {
    orignialData** W_;

public:

    dataClass(char* filename);

    void addData();
    void viewAll();
};

dataClass::dataClass(char* filename) {


    fstream file;

    file.open(filename, ios::in);

    if (file.fail()) {
        cout << "There was an error reading the file...\n";
    }

    W_ = 0;
    W_ = new orignialData*[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        W_[i] = new orignialData;

    char buff[30];
    char* temp;

    while(file >> buff) {

        cout << buff << endl;

        static int i = 0;

        W_[i] -> setData(buff);

        i++;
    }

    file.close();

}
```

Comment: Repeat after me: pointers are not containers! Pointers are not containers... pointers are not containers.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `data = s`, write `data = strdup(s)` to make a *copy* of the contents. Otherwise, you will assign the same pointer again and again, and you will overwrite the contents of the memory to which this pointer points again and again. At the end, your temporary buffer will contain the last line of your file, and all the pointers will point to exactly this buffer. That's what you are observing...